# Tagging current snapshot artifact in artifactory

Tags: maven, artifactory

I need to be able to tag the current snapshot artifact when I publish to artifactory. The reason for this is because I need to store the tag in a manifest inside the artifact.

At the time of publishing the artifact I won't know the exact timestamp as it would be stored in Artifactory

I have tagging working though it applies it to all artifacts of a certain snapshot. Not the artifact being published.

I just need to limit it to the one being published

The syntax for tagging is

```
Usage: PUT /api/storage/{repoKey}{itemPath}?properties=p1=v1[,v2][|p2=v3][&recursive=1]
```

I can't seem to be able to get more granularity than <version>-SNAPSHOT

Many thanks

Comment: Do you need to tag the latest SNAPSHOT or the older ones?

Comment: Hi. I just need the tag to apply to the latest snapshot. Currently it tags all snapshots for that version. I'm thinking of pulling back the list of snapshots and just pulling out the last one and using the timestamp version instead of snapshot

Answer (score 0):

[That's](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact) what you need:

`ivy-local/org/acme/1.0-[INTEGRATION]/acme-1.0-[INTEGRATION].jar`

This is the path to latest snapshot.

Comment: Ok thanks, it wasn't clear that [INTEGRATION] was the latest snapshot

Comment: Unable to get it working at the moment. Its giving me 404s. If I substitute the [INTEGRATION] for the timestamp I can retrieve it. So ivy-local/org/acme/1.0-SNAPSHOT/acme-1.0-<TIMESTAMP>.jar. Using the working URL with the double [INTEGRATION] as per your example doesn't resolve